# Python logging to write all level logs to file

Tags: python, logging

```
import logging

def set_logging():
    logging.basicConfig(
        format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
        level=logging.INFO,
        datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'
        )
    logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
    fl = logging.FileHandler("myapp.log")
    fl.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.addHandler(fl)
    return logger

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger = set_logging()
    logger.info('infoooo')
    logger.error('erorrrr')

Output:
/home/admin# python logging.py
09/08/2019 02:40:36 PM INFO infoooo
09/08/2019 02:40:36 PM ERROR erorrrr
/home/admin# cat myapp.log
infoooo
erorrrr
```

If i comment out logging.basicConfig() line in above code, output is not seen in console and only 'erorrrr' message is written to file. What can i change in the above code to write all level logs to file without writing anything to console?

Answer (score 1):

If you just add `logger.propagate = False` this line in `set_logging` function. It will write all levels of log into the file and will not be shown on the console.

```py
def set_logging():
    logging.basicConfig(
        format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
        level=logging.INFO,
        datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'
        )
    logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
    fl = logging.FileHandler("myapp.log")
    fl.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.addHandler(fl)
    logger.propagate = False  # added this line to disable console logs.
    return logger
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `logger.propagate = False` to disable console logging.

```
import logging

def set_logging():
    logging.basicConfig(
        format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
        level=logging.INFO,
        datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'
        )
    logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
    logger.propagate = False
    fl = logging.FileHandler("myapp.log")
    fl.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.addHandler(fl)
    return logger

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger = set_logging()
    logger.info('infoooo')
    logger.error('erorrrr')
```